# Can antlr rule contexts be target independent

Tags: java, c++, antlr4

I would like to know if there is any way to make the following antlr grammar fragment target independent:

```
ifstatement locals [long condition = 0, long branch = 0, long end = 0]: ifpart[_localctx] thenpart[_localctx] (elifpart[_localctx] thenpart[_localctx])* (elsepart[_localctx])? 'fi';

ifpart [IfstatementContext base] : 'if' boolexpr ;

thenpart [IfstatementContext base] : 'then' statements ;

elifpart [IfstatementContext base] : 'elif' boolexpr ;

elsepart [IfstatementContext base] : 'else' statements ;
```

This seems to work fine in Java, but the code produced by antlr fails to compile when using the Cpp target.    I do not have any actions or predicates in the grammar.

My intended target is C++, but I intended to have the actions for each rule implemented by a listener rather than putting them in the grammar directly so that the grammar could still be analyzed and used by the java-based development tools that come with antlr, and I do not want to have to maintain two separate grammar files.  On the Cpp target for the above grammar fragment, the parameter types for each of the other rules need to each be changed to `IfstatementContext *` which is not valid syntax for Java.

In terms of intent and design, in case it is relevant to understand what I am trying to do, is for the listener for the parser to have pre and post methods for the various components of the if statement, updating the local fields in the ifstatement context as they go so that correct code is outputted to handle flow control correctly in one pass.  I would be using the long values as references to points in the code that need to be patched later with updated address information as each of the various if statement fragments complete.  Please note, **I am not asking how to write the Listener code**.

I would, however, very much like to know how to have these references to contexts in an antlr grammar in a target-independent way, if it is at all possible.

If any further details are required, please indicate so in the comments section and I shall try to address any and all specific questions.

Comment: Make an attempt in C++ and show your code and you might get a better answer.

Comment: I said that I do not need to know how to write the C++ code.  I am asking about writing an ANTLR grammar rule that takes a rule context as a parameter and that  equally be used by the C++ target and Java target.

Answer (score 1):

Action and predicate code is always written in the target language. There's no way around it. If you need platform agnostic behavior then don't use actions or predicates.

That being said, there is a way that you could go, by using only expressions that are supported in all possible target languages. For example simple variable names, `if-then-else` constructs with curly braces, function calls and things like that are pretty much the same in languages like C++, Java and C#. Python/PHP/Swift are significantly different and Javascript/Typescript often needs the `this` prefix (but are otherwise compatible).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I do not need any actions or predicates in my grammar, however.  The only thing I had wanted to mention in the grammar was some means to describe the state tied to particular rules that would ultimately be managed and manipulated by a separately compiled tree listener.   I had been expecting that there was some way of simply having rule contexts be a part of that state and still be target independent, but the mechanism for doing appears non obvious, if it is there at all.  To be honest, I was surprised ....

Comment: ...that the above grammar did not work correctly in the cpp target, as the practical use of rule contexts being passed by value in listener methods that are called back from antlr rather than by the pointer value held by _localctx seems dubious.

Comment: But as soon as you try to access internal structures (like the current parse context) you will end up in target land using action code. My advice is to avoid all that and do any further processing in a semantic step, after the parse run (i.e. in a listener or visitor).

Comment: The listener and visitor both accept a pointer to the context as their only parameter.  But when one has a C++ target in mind, there does not appear to be any way to put another rule context into that context without making the grammar itself target dependent.   Where else other than the rule's context is one supposed to put things like state that is supposed to be tied to the invocation of a particular rule?

Comment: You cannot modify the passed-in contexts in the listeners and visitors, nor can you add own fields to the exsting contexts, but you can build up any structure you want in a derived class, while you walk the parse tree. This is often used to build a symbol table or convert the parse tree to an AST.

Comment: "You cannot modify the passed-in contexts in the listeners and visitors" In the C++ target, the ctx parameter is not a pointer to const. Why couldn't the values its members have be freely read and written to while the rule or any of its children are active? The problem I am facing is that because these members need to be specified in the parser grammar as arguments or locals, there does not seem to be any target independent way to describe their type in many cases, particularly for references to other rule contexts, nor specify the current rule's context to be a parameter for other rules.

Comment: ... and this is entirely independent of whether or not the grammar happens to contain any action or predicate code at all.